# linq query sum products across multiple collections

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two datasets that look like this:

```
+------------------------------------+
| Products                           |
+------------------------------------+
| Id | Name             | Price      |
+------------------------------------+
|  1 | apples           | 1.00       |
|  2 | oranges          | 2.00       |
|  3 | pomengrate       | 3.00       |
+------------------------------------+

+-------------------------------+
| Sales                         |
+-------------------------------+
| CustId | ProductId | Quantity |
+-------------------------------+
|      1 |         1 |        5 |
|      1 |         2 |        4 |
|      1 |         3 |        2 |
|      2 |         1 |        8 |
|      2 |         3 |        7 |
+-------------------------------+
```

I want to get the amount that each customer is spending, essentially ending up with a result like this:

```
+----------------+
| CustId | Total |
+----------------+
|      1 | 19.00 |
|      2 | 29.00 |
+----------------+
```

I can do a sum across a single table but the Sum method in LINQ takes a lambda with only one argument: the reference to the table that the values being summed are in.  These values are in different tables.  How do I sum these together?

Comment: LINQ in general has nothing to do with databases. What ORM are you using? (Linq2SQL?)

Comment: It is linqtosql, but as I understand linq the syntax should be the same whether it's a database read or if Products and Sales are collections of objects that are structured as above

Comment: @Cameron, your comment doesn't relate to his question in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness sake, here's the query syntax version (utilizing joins as opposed to a subselect):

```
var totals =
    from sale in sales
    join prod in product on sale.ProductId equals prod.Id
    let saleProds = new { sale.CustId, Total = prod.Price * sale.Quantity }
    group saleProds by saleProds.CustId into custSale
    select new { Customer = custSale.Key, Total = custSale.Sum(tr => tr.Total) };
```

The key part is that you need to somehow transform the joined collection results (sale and prod) into a single entity that can then be grouped by.

Answer (score 4):

```
var totals =
    from sale in Sales
    group sale by sale.CustId into custSales
    select new
    {
        CustId = custSales.Key, 
        Total = (
            from custSale in custSales
            select custSale.Product.Price *
                custSale.Quantity)
            .Sum()
    };
```

Comment: That's going to just give me the total number of items that the customer has purchased, not the amount of money that the customer has spent

Comment: You'd have to do a join: `from sale in Sales join prod in Products on prod.ID equals sale.ProductID`. This will generate the correct SQL with a single join as opposed to a subselect.

Comment: @SPFiredrake: You don't have to use a join. LINQ to SQL will generate the correct SQL for you (and except when there are performance problems, who cares whether the generated SQL uses a join or a subselect). That's the nice thing about LINQ -> DB.

Comment: @Steven, sorry, but useless edit to be able to remove downvote ;) (and +)

Comment: @Steven Ignoring best practices because "LINQ to SQL will generate the correct SQL for you" is a horribly misguided statement and should not be taught. You still get the correct result, yes, but if there are millions of sale records, then this will take ages to complete compared to a proper join.

Comment: in "select custSale.Product.Price"  the Product part is not working

Comment: Not a fan of StyleCop I see ;) +1 though

Comment: @SPFiredrake: You assume that the OP has a table with millions of records. I can’t seem to find anything about this in his question. You should always start off by writing the most readable code. Premature optimization is a terrible practice.

Comment: @JoeTuskan: I'm a big fan and fanatic user of StyleCop :-). Which part of that code does not validate?

Comment: Hrm, I didn't get much sleep last night, sorry for being a hater. Looks good today :)

Comment: @Steven Whether he has 1 record or 1 million, he shouldn't ignore best practices. Your solution won't scale very well, and that's why I wouldn't recommend it. But hey, as long as it "just works", who cares if its slower, right?

Comment: There is more in life than SQL best practices. There are also best practices in writing code. As long as it is fast enough, there is no need of obscuring it. Big LINQ statements with many joins can become very unreadable. But I believe we won't agree on this, which is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Give this a shot. It gives the results you were looking for:

```
var results = sales.Join(products,
    sale => sale.ProductID,
    product => product.ID,
    (sale, product) => new { CustID = sale.CustID, Total = sale.Quantity * product.Price })
    .GroupBy(r => r.CustID)
    .Select(g => new { CustID = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(gt => gt.Total) });
```

Comment: that one works. +1 ... cant get the group working in my query syntax approach, probably too late now